# Making a magazine for Kindle

Tags: kindle

I am curious as to how people make reading material for Kindle. Does it require programming knowledge? I would think maybe HTML or XML or something? Is there a software to handle everything? If I wanted to make a magazine for people to read with their Kindles, what might be the steps for me to take to reach that goal?

Answer (score -3, accepted):

You can read about the file formats supported by Kindle [here](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Amazon_Kindle#File_formats). Basically all you need to do is produce a pdf.

Comment: Wow, I thought there was so much more than meets the eye.

Comment: This is actually misleading because the PDF will be converted to .mobi and depending on the content of the PDF it will be more or less distorted. I tried two different PDFs yesterday and the kindle preview showed them so messed up that I would never publish them like that...

Comment: Unfortunately I cannot delete the answer.

Answer (score 6):

You might try Amazon's Kindle Publisher page [Kindle's Publishing Program](http://www.amazon.com/gp/feature.html?docId=1000234621). 
It contains tools to convert HTML, XHTML, XML (OPF/IDPF format), or ePub source into a Kindle Book, and it also includes a Kindle viewer, so you can see what your book will look like on a Kindle.

Answer (score 1):

I use the free version of RawCode from  [Kinser Publishing](http://www.kinserpublishing.com/rawcode.html). They have one with a 'visual' writer to make it easier, but I didn't try it yet. Saves to an HTML page to upload to amazon for conversion.